# $resource:badcfg in save method, which seems to return an object

Tags: angularjs, rest, express, mean-stack, angular-resource

Here is my resource

```
var gamesRes = $resource('/collections/test13/:id', 
  {gameID: '@id'}
  );
```

and what i'm trying to do

```
  $scope.res = gamesRes.save({}, $scope.newGame);
```

If i'm setting isArray: true to save method it works fine.
Strange thing is that i don't see, that $scope.res is really an array, in debugger it looks like an object

```
res:  { 
player1: sdf
player2: sdf
}
```

And I need to look like an object, not an array.

Also here is post method in server

```
app.post('/collections/:collectionName', function(req, res, next) {
  req.collection.insert(req.body, {}, function(e, results){
    if (e) return next(e)
    res.send(results)
  })
})
```

What i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you look at what end point is being hit, you are not going to the one you think you are going to.

`{gameID: '@id'}` should probably be `{id: '@gameID'}` to indicate that the `:id` in `/collections/test13/:id` would map to `gameID`attribute in the object you are saving.

Really, you are hitting your list endpoint (because the ID is being left off of the URL) and thus getting a list back.

Comment: I think i didn't get what is it need for earlier. Anyway, i don't use it now, but i get the same error even if resource looks like     var gamesRes = $resource('/collections/test13/');